# Updating a new SQL column with values from the table

Tags: sql, insert

I'm using SQL to perform a basic calculation and I can't figure out the correct syntax. I have a table where I want to add a new column, and to populate the values of that column using a combination of the existing values. Here is the code that I am illustrating the problem with.

```
-- create a table
CREATE TABLE test (
x numeric(10,3),
y numeric(10,3)
);

-- add some sample values
INSERT INTO test (x,y) VALUES( 7,3 );
INSERT INTO test (x,y) VALUES( 8,4 );

-- add a new column
ALTER TABLE test ADD testcalc numeric(10,3);

-- values in new column (testcalc) using the sum of values from x and y
INSERT INTO 
    test (testcalc) 
SELECT 
    t.x + t.y
FROM
    test as t;
```

This produces the following table:

[image]

I understand that the values are being inserted as new rows, but how can I add them as values to my column so that the table is structured like this?

```
x | y | testcalc
7 | 3 | 10
8 | 4 | 12
```

Comment: Ah, so my example involves trivial data. I'm performing a more sophisticated query, but did not know how to update the table with my results! Much to learn in the world of `SQL`!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT` in such a way in the last part of the query:

```
UPDATE test SET
testcalc = x + y

SELECT * FROM test
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `UPDATE` instead if `INSERT`

```
UPDATE test
SET testcalc = x + y
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of sql  will be

```
Update tablename set newcolumn=old_col1+old_col2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use update command and not Insert!